# Plotting multiple lines in one graph with legends

Tags: plotting, legending

I have to plot two functions in one plot. I have added the following code to generate the graph.

```
Prat = 1.25;
wp = 1/(1 + Prat*Erat)
Plot1 = Plot[wp, {Erat, 0, 0.99}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(p\)]\)", 
     None}, {"\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\
\[Epsilon]\), \(o\)]\)/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(p\)]\)", 
     None}},
  ImagePadding -> 55,
  PlotStyle -> Blue, ImagePadding -> 25, 
  Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
  FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic},
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Cambria", 12, GrayLevel[0]}]
wo = 1/(1 + 1/Prat*1/Erat)
Plot2 = Plot[wo, {Erat, 0, 0.99}, ImagePadding -> 55,
  PlotStyle -> Red,
  Axes -> False, Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
  FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Black},
  FrameLabel -> {{None, 
     "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(o\)]\)"}, {None, None}},
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Cambria", 12, GrayLevel[0]}]
Overlay[{Plot1, Plot2}]
Export["weights.pdf", %]
```

However, I don't have an idea how to change the colour to black and white as it is required for a paper. I want one line to be solid black and another line to be dotted with legends added in the graph. I also tried the following code to generate mulitiple plot

```
ResourceFunction["MultipleAxesPlot"][{wp, wo}, {Erat, 0, 1}], but I think adding legend and axes labels here is tricky. Can someone help?
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the PlotStyle to Blue/Red, set it to Black/{Dashed,Black:

```
Prat = 1.25;
wp = 1/(1 + Prat*Erat);
Plot1 = Plot[wp, {Erat, 0, 0.99}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(p\)]\)", 
      None}, {"\[InvisiblePrefixScriptBase]\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\
\(\[Epsilon]\), \(o\)]\)/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Epsilon]\), \(p\)]\)",
       None}}, ImagePadding -> 55, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   ImagePadding -> 25, Frame -> {True, True, True, False}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Automatic}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Cambria", 12, GrayLevel[0]}, 
   Epilog -> {Text["Curve 1", Scaled[{0.9, 0.2}]]}];
wo = 1/(1 + 1/Prat*1/Erat);
Plot2 = Plot[wo, {Erat, 0, 0.99}, ImagePadding -> 55, 
   PlotStyle -> {Black, Dashed}, Axes -> False, 
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, None}}, 
   FrameStyle -> {Automatic, Automatic, Automatic, Black}, 
   FrameLabel -> {{None, 
      "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Omega]\), \(o\)]\)"}, {None, None}}, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Cambria", 12, GrayLevel[0]}, 
   Epilog -> {Text["Curve 2", Scaled[{0.9, 0.8}]]}];
Overlay[{Plot1, Plot2}]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: But, how to add legend to the plot showing which line shows what?

Comment: You may use "Epilog". I added this to my answer.